# Is it possible to set custom desktop resolution on selenium with python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, resolution

I can set custom window size with python, but can detect my desktop resolution anyway. I need to change screenResolution = 1920,1080
availableScreenResolution = 1920,1032 with selenium chrome. Is it possible?

Comment: _I can set custom window size with python_: Code trials please?

Comment: `driver.set_window_size(1366,768)` and `options.add_argument("--window-size=1366,768")` tried both

Comment: Why do you need to change screen resolution? Is not enough changing driver window size?

Comment: In order to manipulate the browser fingerprint, I need to change screen resolution, changing window size doesn't help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Screen resolution is retrieved from the screen object.  If you enter the console and type screen you will see the values and properties.

You can execute javascript to change the obejct's values like this

```
driver.execute_script(js)
Object.defineProperty(screen, "availHeight", {
    value: 200,
})
```

The problem is this object refreshes with every change of location so you'd probably need an extension that executes this every time the browser makes a request

EDIT you can use event handlers to trigger it every time you navigate
[trigger python events driven by selenium controlled browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57532775/trigger-python-events-driven-by-selenium-controlled-browser)

Comment: Ok no this doesn't work, but maybe a step in the right direction